# Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt - build all solution files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

Is there a way to search for all the solution files (.sln) in a given directory, and build them all?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using batch or PowerShell to find the fileset and then drive the commandline invocation of the build process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this batch file:

```
for /F %%a in ('dir *.sln /s/b') do msbuild "%%a"
```